# Required: Android.widget.CursorAdapter Found: Android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

Declaration of `myAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
   }
```

Usage:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // adds item to action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

    // Get Search item from action bar and Get Search service
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);
        // Getting selected (clicked) item suggestion
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

                // Add clicked text to search box
                CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
                Cursor cursor = ca.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                searchView.setQuery(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fishName")),false);
                return true;
            }
```

The lines that gets me the error:

```
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And:

```
CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
```

Errors:

**Error:(218, 46) error: incompatible types: SimpleCursorAdapter cannot be converted to CursorAdapter**

**Error:(225, 72) error: incompatible types: android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter cannot be converted to android.widget.CursorAdapter**

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://androidcss.com/android/android-autocomplete-search-suggestions/).

I don't quite get why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me shed a light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your imports, CursorAdapter exists both in the regular and support libraries, so make it consistent inside all of your classes.

```
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
```

Comment: It fixed this line: `CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();` This, however, still returns an error: `searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);` as follows on the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/qb7ahIv.jpg

Comment: Change SimpleCursorAdapter import to : import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;